# Restful web service in java to power turn-based iOS and Android games

Tags: web-services, rest, multiplayer

I'm getting started with creating the back-end architecture to support a turn-based mobile game. Most of my research tells me that a stateless web server should work just fine, because the client is not always connected to the server.

My question is, how would I write the logic for GET requests. If I need a user to be updated when his or her opponent has made a move...do I keep doing GET requests every few seconds? Isn't it a big problem that the server is one-directional, as in the server can't notify the user when it is his/her move? Or am I overestimating it, and doing a GET requests every other second is perfectly fine?

Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same.  Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider the use of WebSockets:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

And even if you are not using a browser, with iOS you can open a connection to the socket which uses port 80 (you don't need any extra rules). WenSockets providie a standardized way for the server to send content to the browser without being solicited by the client, and allowing for messages to be passed back and forth while keeping the connection open.